# Cannot save Custom Post Type meta data

Tags: custom-post-types

I've created a custom post type with one meta box.  I've already tried everything, but its still not saving the value.  Please help.

```
 add_action('init', 'create_post_type');

 function create_post_type() {
 register_post_type('jh_dedications',
        array(
                'labels' => array (
                                    'name' => __('Dedications'),
                                    'singular_name' => __('Dedication')
                                    ),
                                    'public' => true,
                                    'has_archive' => true,
                                    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
                                    'show_ui' => true
                                    )
                    );
 }

 add_action ("add_meta_boxes", "add_dedications_jh");

 function add_dedications_jh() {
add_meta_box('jh_datepicker', 'Select Date', 'jh_datepicker', 'jh_dedications', 'side', 'default');
 }

 function jh_datepicker() {
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$dedicationDate = $custom["dedicationDate"][0];

?>
<input type="text" name="dedicationDate" value="<?php echo $dedicationDate; ?>" /> 
<?php 
 }

 add_action('wp_insert_post_data', 'jh_save_dedication');

 function jh_save_dedication() {
global $post;

if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return $post->ID;

update_post_meta($post->ID, "dedicationDate", $POST["dedicationDate"]); 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

[php superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) is `$_POST`, not `$POST`.

```
update_post_meta($post->ID, "dedicationDate", $_POST["dedicationDate"]);
```